# Каким образом можно сделать вращение svg circle?

Tags: svg, анимация

у меня есть такие 4 круга через SVG. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно добавить для них анимацию вращение? Вращение будет заметно так как их цвет сделан через Gradient
Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно навесить на них класс и анимировать его в css, как обычный, любой другой элемент. Ну или айдишники раздать, если планируется разная анимация. Я не спец по svg, но это, кажется, самый простой способ.

Comment: Проблема в том что при свойстве rotate он не двигается как круг а двигается относительно всего блока

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи атрибута `transform='rotate(deg, x y)'` можно вращать элементы `svg` вокруг определенной точки, в данном примере эта точка - центр круга...

```js
let draw = t => {
  circle.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${t/5}, 50 50)`)
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<svg>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="gold"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="teal"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#grad)" id="circle"></circle> 
</svg>
```

---

Точно так же это работает с группой элементов:

```js
let draw = t => {
  g.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${t/5}, 50 50)`)
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<svg>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="gold"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="teal"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <g id="g">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="35" fill="url(#grad)"></circle> 
    <circle cx="95" cy="50" r="5"></circle>
  </g >
</svg>
```